# Python - Tkinter Button Command not Working

Tags: python, button, tkinter, listbox

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.search_var = StringVar()
        self.search_var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.update_list())
        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.search_var, width=13)
        self.lbox = Listbox(self, width=50, height=30, selectmode=EXTENDED)
        self.rbox = Listbox(self, width=50, height=30)
        self.btnGet = Button(self, text="Add to Selection", command=self.get_selection())

        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.lbox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.rbox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.btnGet.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)

        self.update_list()

    def get_selection(self):
        print("Get Selection")
        items = [self.lbox_list[int(item)] for item in self.lbox.curselection()]
        print(items)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Filter Listbox Test')
    app = Application(master=root)
    print('Starting mainloop()')
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

My code reads from an XML file and populates a listbox. I want a button to copy my selection from lbox to rbox. However my button doesn't seem to fire and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying a command in tkinter you should use:

```
command=self.get_selection
```

Instead of:

```
command=self.get_selection()
```

Similar to defining a function for your thread! Otherwise it will not properly associate your function with the command